# exit() the program from parent before child process has terminated

Tags: c, fork, kill

I have a C server. This server has to handle multiple connections **and** user's input (through a simple ncurses GUI). So I created two childs.
My problem comes when from the main menu of the user interface, I need to `exit` the program (then terminate the second child process *-which handles the connections-* from the first child process).

I'll try to explain myself with a little example:

```
int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    int status1, status2;
    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        perror("main fork failure:");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid == 0){
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            /*  
                some stuff the second child does while 
                the first child is already running
            */
        }
        /* this is the first child */
        int choice;
        choice = menu();
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                /* 
                   HERE I have to exit (from the first child first,
                   and from the program then): how can I kill the
                   second child that is running to prevent
                   zombie processes? 
                */
                // kill() which pid?
                exit(2);
                break;
        }
        wait(&status2);
    }
    wait(&status1);
    return 0;
}
```

So, how can I `kill` it if I don't know the second child `pid` from the first child?

Comment: A child should not kill his/her parents. Your problem is about design. You should use `thread` or `select`(if you are on linux you can add 0 to select, not portable).

Comment: `select`? I use it to handle the sockets, what does it has to do with my problem? Are you talking about using `select` in a way related to `fork`?

Comment: my point is that your use of `fork()` is not the purpose of it. `fork()` create a new **process**, that do the job that you want it do. Here you want that your child kill your the parent. This is not the purpose of `fork()`. You should use a thread that handle ncurses. With a variable `running`, set to false when thread stop. The main program will stop when this variable is  false. Or use select to handle `0`. So you could read the user input with ncurses.

Comment: actually the *first child* has to kill his own child (that I called *second child* in my question), not the parent... Still a bad behaviour? I woudn't like to change my code again introducing the threads. I mean, if I have to, I'll do it, but I'd rather not

Comment: You lost me. Who is ncurses? Who need to kill who? If you want kill a child in the parent it's easy your have his pid return by fork. You are very unclear. You could use [`getpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) before fork so the child know the pid of his parent but it's **very ugly**.

Comment: @Stargateur: As far as I can tell, the child is not killing its parent; the first child process is killing its own child when it (the first child) is told to exit.  The main parent just hangs around waiting for its own (singleton) child to exit.  The child itself creates a second child, and presumably communicates with it on occasion, and then is required to arrange to kill its child when it is told to exit (commit suicide?).  Process hierarchies end up using morbid terminology!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah you got me perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you reuse the variable `pid`, but fortunately, the non-zero `pid` is the one you need to signal.

Hence:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern int menu(void);

static void wait_for_pid(int pid)
{
    int status;
    int corpse;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) >= 0 && corpse != pid)
        printf("Unexpected child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    if (corpse == pid)
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    else
        printf("Child %d died without its death being tracked\n", pid);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("main fork failure:");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("child fork failure:");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            pause();    /* Do nothing until signalled */
            exit(0);
        }
        /* this is the first child */
        int choice = menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            /* action 1 */
            break;
        case 2:
            kill(pid, SIGTERM);
            exit(2);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
        wait_for_pid(pid);
        exit(0);
    }
    wait_for_pid(pid);
    return 0;
}
```

The loop in the `wait_for_pid()` function should be overkill for the child, but the parent process could have children it doesn't know about under some circumstances — unlikely but not impossible circumstances.

The use of `pause()` in the second child is simply writing some code; it is not useful and would not therefore be what you'd write there.  Writing the comment `/* action 1 */` is likewise dummy code; you'd replace it with code that does something useful.  I'd probably have functions to call for the first child and the second child, rather than embedding much code in `main()`.  I assume that it's written as shown to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)); thank you for keeping the code small.

---

The code above was untested because there was no `menu()` function.  The code below has a menu function — not that it is very interactive.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern int menu(void);

int menu(void)
{
    printf("Dozing...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Menu option 2 chosen\n");
    return 2;
}

static void wait_for_pid(int pid)
{
    int status;
    int corpse;
    int curpid = getpid();
    printf("%d: waiting for children to die\n", curpid);
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) >= 0 && corpse != pid)
        printf("%d: Unexpected child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", curpid, corpse, status);
    if (corpse == pid)
        printf("%d: Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", curpid, corpse, status);
    else
        printf("%d: Child %d died without its death being tracked\n", curpid, pid);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("main fork failure:");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("child fork failure:");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("Second child (%d) - pausing\n", (int)getpid());
            pause();    /* Do nothing until signalled */
            printf("Second child (%d) - awake despite no signal handling\n", (int)getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
        /* this is the first child */
        printf("First child (%d) - menuing\n", (int)getpid());
        int choice = menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            /* action 1 */
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("kill(%d, SIGTERM)\n", pid);
            kill(pid, SIGTERM);
            wait_for_pid(pid);
            exit(2);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
        /* Reached on menu choices != 2 */
        /* Probably needs a loop around the menu() - end loop before wait_for_pid()  */
        wait_for_pid(pid);
        exit(0);
    }
    wait_for_pid(pid);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, a sample output sequence was:

```
19489: waiting for children to die
First child (19490) - menuing
Dozing...
Second child (19491) - pausing
Menu option 2 chosen
kill(19491, SIGTERM)
19490: waiting for children to die
19490: Child 19491 exited with status 0x000F
19489: Child 19490 exited with status 0x0200
```

All of which looks as would be expected.  You can see the death from SIGTERM in the status 0x000F (SIGTERM is normally 15, and is 15 on macOS Sierra, though AFAIK no standard demands that it is 15).  You can see the first child exited normally with status 2 from the 0x0200.  You can see that the parent started waiting before the children did anything.  And you can see the debugging techniques — copious printing and including the PID most of the time.

Comment: Yeah, i created that example to avoid to copy my long code. Thanks for your time. I'll try this later on and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hey @JonathanLeffler I just tested it and it seems it doesn't work... Basically it seems it copies the *first child* process, I don't know. I think it executes its instructions 2 times and simultaneously. I say this because when I run it, it repeats the printfs (of the *first child*), and when it starts ncurses it basically crashes.

Comment: However the *second child* works fine and there's not anymore the process zombie that keeps my file open.

Comment: Wait, I don't know how but now it works it all. I just uncommented a `for(;;)` loop -that has `select` inside and all the stuff to handle the connections- inside the *second child*. Well, thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it: it must be because without the `for(;;)`, the *second child* terminated before. Wowsers.

Comment: Glad you've resolved it.  I've updated the answer with the debug code I was using when I got your "doesn't work" message.